# Application Pool is Automatically Stop in IIS 7

Tags: iis

My Application pool is automatically stops after someday then I have create separate application pool for sendemail services, but database log is not download so what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should look through your event logs and IIS logs to track down your issue. Then make the changes necessary to correct it.

For more information, see:

• http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732079(v=ws.10).aspx

• http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722404.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason could be, you changed the domain username or password but in IIS app pool you would have not updated. The solution:

1. Double click application pool
2. Go to the application pool which is stopped
3. Right click and advanced settings
4. Under Process Model -> Identity -> custom account ->give your correct domain user name and password.

Hope this might solve the issue for somebody.